# Find text in <li> and add image into this <li>

Tags: jquery, html

I have this list `<ul>` with `<li>`

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
  <li><a href="status.html">Status</a></li>
  <li><a href="logpoll.html">Live Log</a></li>
  <li><a href="config.html">Config</a></li>
  <li><a href="readers.html">Readers</a></li>
  <li><a href="userconfig.html">Users</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="files.html">Files</a></li>
  <li><a href="failban.html">Failban</a></li>
  <li><a href="cacheex.html">CacheEX</a></li>
  <li><a href="script.html">Scripts</a></li>
  <li><a href="shutdown.html">Restart</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need solution to find `<li>` with some text and add image into this `<li>` e.g.:

```
  <li><img src="image1.jpg"><a href="status.html">Status</a></li>
  <li><img src="image2.jpg"><a href="logpoll.html">Live Log</a></li>
```

I know this solution

```
  $('li:contains("Status")').prepend('Links for image');
```

But i think that is too complicated.

Idea: add text from LI to VAR and then compare throught IF e.g.

```
  var text = "text from LI"
  if(page == 'status'){  
      // add image to LI.
  }
```

Comment: and may I know why you think so?

Comment: What is your question? Why is it too complicated?

Comment: Your solution looks good if you have no class or id for each list element. Or you can use eq selector if your menu item order always the same.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Only training for me :-)

Comment: if you want to do comparison approach like that,  use `filter(fn)`. You actually have a better control than `:contains` logic provides because you have access to the element itself in the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want here.  Using your code I created a fiddle for you (with some options).

**It revolves around something like this:**

`$("li").append('<img src="image1.jpg">');` and then I expand that concept with an `.each()` loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/28L05o22/

Enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("li").html("<img src='image1.jpg'/>");
```